How to write an integration Spring Boot Test for a Camunda process?
How do I write an integration test in Spring Boot to test a Camunda process?
The tasks in the Camunda process that need testing also have services that call methods to make REST calls, these would need to be mocked.
e.g.
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ProcessTaskDelegate implements JavaDelegate {

    @Autowired
    ProcessService processService;

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution delegateExecution) throws Exception {
        String input = delegateExecution.getVariable("input");
        
        String response = processService.doTask(input);
    

So far I have used mockMvc to call an endpoint that begins the Camunda process. I have then been trying to use @MockBean to mock the necessary services.
Running the test produces inconsistent results, sometimes the mocks are interacted with and other times they are not. I doubt I have the configuration correct or this just doesn't work...
Is there a better way to do this?
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class CamundaIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    @MockBean
    private ProcessService processService;

    @MockBean
    private ProcessServiceTwo processServiceTwo;

    private MyRequest request;


    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        assert(mvc != null);
        assert(mapper != null);
        assert(processService != null);
        assert(processServiceTwo != null);
        request = TestHelper.generateRequest();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCamundaProcess() throws Exception {

        when(processService.doTask(anyString())).thenReturn(TestHelper.getResponse());
        when(processServiceTwo.doAnotherTask(anyString())).thenReturn("Success");

        mvc.perform(post("/process/initiate")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(request))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

        verify(processService).doTask(anyString());
        verify(processServiceTwo).doAnotherTask(anyString());

    }


If you are using Camunda 8, the Camunda docs has a section that covers writing tests for processes using the Camunda Process Test (CPT), a Java library for testing BPMN processes and process applications.
This uses JUnit instead of mockMvc, but it has fleshed-out examples of how to test all parts of your process.
